# "Integer expression expected" bash if statements

Tags: bash, shell, awk, integer, expression

I'm trying to extract the xy coordinates of some earthquake occurrences along with their magnitudes from a file "seismic_c_am.txt", and plot them as circles of various sizes and colours based on the magnitude. Here is what I have so far:

```
25  i=`awk '{ FS = "|" ; print $11}' seismic_c_am.txt`
26
27  if [ "$i" -gt 7 ] ; then
28    awk 'NR%25==0 { FS = "|" ; print $4, $3}' seismic_c_am.txt | psxy $rgn $proj -Sc0.25c -Gred -O -K >> $psfile ;
29  fi
30
31  if [ "$i" -gt 5 ] && [ "$i" -le 7 ] ; then
32  awk 'NR%25==0 { FS = "|" ; print $4, $3}' seismic_c_am.txt | psxy $rgn $proj -Sc0.2c -Gorange -O -K >> $psfile ;
33  fi
34
35  if [ "$i" -le 5 ] ; then
36  awk 'NR%25==0 { FS = "|" ; print $4, $3}' seismic_c_am.txt | psxy $rgn $proj -Sc0.1c -Gyellow -O -K >> $psfile ;
37  fi
```

This script seems to just print all the magnitudes ($11) into the terminal, and the last line reads:

```
.
.
3.6
4.0
1.7
3.6 : integer expression expected
```

But I don't know which line this is referring to! Possibly line 27, 31 or 35? (see above)

Comment: `5.5` is not an integer, there's your problem. Same with the variables. You can't do floating-point maths in bash. Instead of calling awk so many times, you should try and combine the scripts together.

Comment: I've replaced the "5.5"s with "5"s, same issue. Does $i have to be an integer?

Comment: @co323 yes both $i and the other value has to be integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't do floating point arithmetic, only integer arithmetic.

Since you're comparing with integers, you can make awk print the integer part.

```
i=`awk '{ FS = "|" ; printf "%d", $11}' seismic_c_am.txt`
```

If you want to know which line is causing these errors, add the command `set -x` to your script to turn on tracing mode: bash will print each script line before executing it. If you only want to trace part of the script, you can turn off tracing with `set +x`.

Since you're repeating the same snippet many times, you may want to restructure your script a bit.

```
i=`awk '{ FS = "|" ; printf "%d", $11}' seismic_c_am.txt`
if [ $i -ge 7 ]; then
  sc_value=0.25 color=red
elif [ $i -ge 5 ]; then
  sc_value=0.2 color=orange
else
  sc_value=0.1 color=yellow
fi
awk 'NR%25==0 { FS = "|" ; print $4, $3}' seismic_c_am.txt |
psxy $rgn $proj -Sc${sc_value}c -G$color -O -K >> $psfile
```

Comment: Is it OK to do multiple assignments on the same line like that? Also, I'd probably go with `$(` instead of backticks. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: @TomFenech Sure, you can have any number of assignments on the same line (whether or not they're followed by a command). I don't use backticks in my own script either, and I always use double quotes around variable substitutions, but I didn't want to change the script too much beyond the point I wanted to convey.

Comment: Thanks guys this is great input. Gilles that fixed it for me cheers

Comment: I do suggest you replace old and outdated back-tics with parentheses like this: `i=$(awk 'code')`